# How to use Groovy jenkins directory path as an Array

Tags: loops, jenkins, groovy

I am checking out files from git to jenkins in this format:

```
local/joules/.../dev/n-1a/pf-as.manifest
local/joules/.../dev/n-2a/pf-as.manifest
local/joules/.../sit/n-3b/pf-as.manifest
local/joules/.../sit/n-4a/pf-as.manifest
local/joules/.../perf/n-3b/pf-as.manifest
local/joules/.../perf/n-4a/pf-as.manifest
```

i want to change this in groovy script something like:

```
pf-as-dev-n-1a.manifest
pf-as-dev-n-2a.manifest
pf-as-sit-n-3b.manifest
pf-as-sit-n-4a.manifest
```

can i do it using some looping mechanism in groovy. I am able to achieve this on by one...but i need to implement it using loop.

I stuggled a lot, but not get yet. Any1 have idea please help.

Comment: Raja Singh, please check the solution to see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
list.map { it.split("/") }.flatMap {
  val lastPart = it.last().split(".")
  val extension = lastPart.last()
  val begin = lastPart.first()
  val middle = it[it.size - 3]
  val end = it[it.size - 2]
  listOf("$begin-$middle-$end.$extension")
}
```

Comment: Sorry didn't realize you wanted Groovy, this is actually Kotlin. But if you can, I'd recommend using that instead :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this easily as below:

```
//list of file paths
def files = ['local/joules/.../dev/n-1a/pf-as.manifest',
'local/joules/.../dev/n-2a/pf-as.manifest',
'local/joules/.../sit/n-3b/pf-as.manifest',
'local/joules/.../sit/n-4a/pf-as.manifest',
'local/joules/.../perf/n-3b/pf-as.manifest',
'local/joules/.../perf/n-4a/pf-as.manifest']

println files.collect{it.substring(it.lastIndexOf('/')+1, it.length())}
```

Quickly try this online <kbd>[demo](https://ideone.com/V6EuKL)</kbd>